# Taking Turns with a Discord.py game

Tags: python, discord.py

**What I'm trying to do:** I'm trying to create turn-based fighting game with discord.py. While the health of both players is more than 0, the message author and the mentioned user would take turns either by using punch, heal, or surrender (self-explanatory).

**Problem:** I'm unsure where to start when it comes to incorporating the switching of turns. Below I've posted the entirety of the code I used for the message author, but I can't seem to find a way to make the next turn happen once the message author has taken a turn, and vice versa.

```py
@client.command()
async def battle(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    aut = 5
    ops = 5
    user = user.mention
    cmam = ctx.message.author.mention
    if user == cmam:
        await ctx.send(f"You can't fight yourself {cmam} <:BlobWuh:761383059349438464>")
    else:
        await ctx.send(f'{cmam} vs {user}, who will win?')
        while aut > 0 and ops > 0:
            await ctx.send(f'{cmam}: `Punch, Heal, Surrender`')

            def check(m):
                return m.content == 'punch' or m.content == 'heal' or m.content == 'surrender' and m.author == ctx.message.author

            response = await client.wait_for('message', check = check)
            if "punch" in response.content.lower():
                if ops > 0:
                    dmg = [0, 1, 2]
                    dmg = (random.choice(dmg))
                    ops = ops - dmg
                    await ctx.send(f"{user} is down to **{ops}** health")
                    if ops <= 0:
                        await ctx.send(f"**{cmam} has won the battle**")
                        break
                elif ops <= 0:
                    await ctx.send(f"**{cmam} has won the battle**")
                    break
            if "heal" in response.content.lower():
                if aut >= 5:
                    await ctx.send(f"{cmam} already has **{aut}** health, they lose a turn")
                else:
                    aut = aut + 1
                    await ctx.send(f"{cmam} now has **{aut}** health")
            if "surrender" in response.content.lower():
                await ctx.send(f"{cmam} has surrendered with **{aut}** health. {user} has claimed victory with **{ops}** health remaining")
                aut = aut - 20
                ops = ops - 20
                break
```

Comment: You could use another variable to store the current turn for whoever. Then just use if statements to alternate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so this is for anyone who stumbles onto this again, it's mostly the same code but there's a turn variable to store the current turn. (Thank you @Ethan M-H for the advice)

```py
@client.command()
async def test(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    turn = 0 #adding a turn variable for turn taking
    aut = 5
    ops = 5
    user = user.mention
    cmam = ctx.message.author.mention
    if user == cmam:
        await ctx.send(f"You can't fight yourself {cmam}")
    else:
        await ctx.send(f"{cmam} vs {user}, who will win?")
        while aut > 0 and ops > 0:

            if turn == 0:
                await ctx.send(f"{cmam}: `test`")
                def check(m):
                    return m.content == "test" and m.author == ctx.message.author
                response = await client.wait_for('message', check = check)
                if "test" in response.content.lower() and turn == 0:#turn == 0 is here since it doesn't work sometimes
                    await ctx.send("a nice test")
                    turn = turn + 1

            elif turn == 1:
                await ctx.send(f"{user}: `test`")
                def check(o):
                    return o.content == "test" and o.author == discord.Member
                response = await client.wait_for('message', check = check)
                if "test" in response.content.lower() and turn == 1:#turn == 1 is here since (elif turn == 1) doesn't work sometimes
                    await ctx.send("the test is strong with this one")
                    turn = turn - 1
```